# Does the higher cohomology of a quasi-coherent sheaf on a Stein manifold vanish?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

It is a well-known result in algebraic geometry that if $X$ is an affine scheme and $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on $X$, then the higher cohomologies of $\mathcal{F}$ vanish, i.e.
$$
H^i(X,\mathcal{F})=0, ~\forall~ i\geq 1.
$$

In complex geometry we have a similar result of of Henri Cartan which claims that if $X$ is a Stein manifold and $\mathcal{F}$ is a coherent sheaf on $X$, then we have
$$
H^i(X,\mathcal{F})=0, ~\forall~ i\geq 1.
$$
See this nlab item: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Stein+manifold#Forstneric11

$\textbf{My question}$ is if we consider the more general case that $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on a Stein manifold $X$, do we still have
$$
H^i(X,\mathcal{F})=0, ~\forall~ i\geq 1?
$$

Here by quasi-coherent I mean $\mathcal{F}$ locally can be written as the cokernel of 
$$
\bigoplus_I\mathcal{O}_X|_U\rightarrow \bigoplus_J\mathcal{O}_X|_U.
$$
(I'm not sure whether there is other version of quasi-coherent sheaf in complex analytic context.)

Comment: a common trick to deal with these issues is to use the fact that any big object (ie quasi-coherent sheaf) is a filtered colimit of small objects (ie coherent sheaves). Since it vanishes for coherent sheaves it must vanish for all quasi-coherent sheaves as cohomology commutes with filtered colimits. (Problem: I know that in the algebraic world any qcoh is colimit of coh; I have no idea whether it holds in the analytic world...)

Comment: @Zhaoting Wei: In section 2.1 of https://eudml.org/doc/10167 (especially Lemmas 2.1.8 and 2.1.9) one finds the equivalence among several possible definitions of quasi-coherence in the analytic setting (written there for the rigid-analytic case but carrying over to the complex-analytic case without difficulty), such as locally being a direct limit of coherent sheaves, or of coherent subsheaves, or your proposed definition. They all fail your question, due to Gabber's example on the open unit disc in Example 2.1.6 of that link.

Comment: @bananastack: The analogy with the algebraic case turns out to be misleading for this question. The notion of quasi-coherence in the analytic setting exhibits some surprises (though also has some decent properties), due to Gabber's example mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @user74230: cool!

Comment: @user74230 Thank you very much for your enlightening comment! Is the result true if we consider the cohomology on compact Stein manifold instead of arbitrary Stein manifold?

Comment: @ZhaotingWei: Since cohomology commutes with direct limits on compact Hausdorff spaces (proved in Godement's book, for example), for your question in the compact case it would suffice to know that a quasi-coherent sheaf in some reasonable sense is globally a direct limit of coherent sheaves when the analytic space is compact.  But I am doubtful that this could be true.

Comment: @bananastack: Note also Example 2.1.10 in that link, which builds on Gabber's example to show that these various equivalent notions of quasi-coherence in the analytic setting aren't preserved under direct limits! (That might sound paradoxical, but it actually isn't.) So it is not really a "good" notion (though useful for some purposes nonetheless).

Comment: @Zhaoting Wei ,There is a notion of quasi-coherent analytic Frechet sheaf due to Ramis and Ruget for which vanishing holds.

Comment: @MohanRamachandran: Curious; the definition looks very "global", and in particular Gabber's examples seem to show that their notion of quasi-coherence cannot be checked locally on the space.  Is that not a headache in practice (or even to make nontrivial examples)?  I suppose it depends how one wishes to use the notion.

Comment: @user74230: Agreed .This notion is used for example in the Kiehl Verdier proof of Grauert direct image theorem.

Comment: @MohanRamachandran: Aha, I have only seen the proof of that theorem in the  book of Grauer and Remmert on coherent analytic sheaves, where the notion wasn't introduced (or at least not named as such, even if it is lurking within the functional analysis there).  Is it used in other contexts?

Comment: @user74230: The proof in Grauert Remmert is due to Forster and Knorr which uses linked system of sheaves which minimizes the functional analysis to the open mapping theorem. The Kiehl Verdier approach uses more functional analysis and Ramis and Ruget use it for Analytic Duality. Bingener and Kosarew use it for Analytic deformation theory.